# Runtime permission in fragment returning wrong grantResult.. i am using `targetSdkVersion 22`

Tags: java, android, permissions, fragment

[image]My CODE : IN fragment:-

```
if (((PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ);

                    }

                    else {

                        share();

                    }
```

And on request permissionResult:-

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted.
            share();
        } else {
            btn_share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CheckConstraint.getbuilder(getActivity(),getString(R.string.please_allow_permission));
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
    else if (requestCode==REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE)
        if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            share();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    }


}
```

In case of `ALLOW` permissionResult is not called and in case of `DENY` `grantResult[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` is `true`. Which is odd because grantResult should be equal to `NOT_GRANTED`..
I can take runtime permission using `targetSdkVersion 22` but i cant handle the result properly..

Comment: **WHY**  `targetSdkVersion 22`???

Comment: FOR TARGETTING LOWER END PHONES...LOWER APIS.. now if i upgrade my targetsdkVersion then for every permission i have to take runtime..

Comment: *Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.**

Comment: this will only work with android version 6.0 api level 23 not less then that.

Comment: My question isnt that...i am asking why i am able to prompt the runtime permission in targetsdk 22 ?? and why am I getting wrong result..

Comment: If i `ALLOW ` in runtime the permission is allowed and if I `DENY` then its denied.. but why is it giving wrong result on `RequestPermissionsResult` ??

Comment: I am testing in `API level 23` itself and its `working` but I cant handle the results thats it..

Comment: If you are lazy to handle runtime permissions, have a look at my library. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: I have to upgrade it to `targetSdkVersion 23` or later then right?